# WebStorm и Live Edit

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, webstorm

Не могу разобраться в webstrom (2016.1.2):

1. Live Edit. Скачал плагин для Хрома, но когда в html файле в всплывающем окне выбираю Хром запускается проект, но без css файла. В плагинах LE есть, но во вкладке View я его не нахожу.
2. Когда выбираю Run для js файла вылазит окно "Error running newjs1.js: Program path not specified". Что это такое?

Answer (score 2):

1. Live edit работает только в процессе отладки, открытие страницы через всплывающее окно (думаю, Вы имеете в виду панель с иконками браузеров в верхнем правом углу редактора) не активирует его. См. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Live+Edit. Не очень поняла про css... В меню View его быть и не должно в последних версиях, интерфейс поменялся
2. не знаю, что за конфигурация создается по умолчанию. Возможно, Вы пытаетесь запустить  newjs1.js как node.js приложение, но путь к Node интерпретатору не указан, и его не удалось найти в PATH. В любом случае, это не то, что нужно делать для запуска web страницы